# Hide UITabBar when pushed while retaining touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I need to hide `UITabBar` on one view controller. I tried

```
vc.hideTabBarwhenpushed = TRUE
```

when pushed; this worked fine, but when I opened a `UITable` on this view controller, then at the bottom where `UITabBar` should be, at that place my `UITable` is not getting touch.
I tried doing

```
[viewController setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
```

but it did't work.

Comment: Are you using a `UITableViewController`?

Comment: whose user interaction i need to check, iApple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that you are setting the springs and struts of your table view correctly:

[image: springs and struts]

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to hide and show your tabBar

//To Hide Tab Bar

```
- (void) hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller 
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        } 
        else 
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
        }

    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

//To Show Tab Bar

```
- (void) showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller 
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 431, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        } 
        else 
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 431)];
        }
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
}
```

Comment: it hides the tab bar but i am still not able to get touch on UItabbar's location for UITableView..