# Not in AppDelegate create TabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

This is RegisterViewController.m part

```
   if ([message isEqualToString:@"registerOK"]){

        self.findViewController = [[FindViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
        self.friendViewController = [[FriendViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
        self.goViewController = [[GoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
        self.settingViewController = [[SettingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];

        self.findNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.findViewController];
        self.friendNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.friendViewController];
        self.goNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.goViewController];
        self.settingNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.settingViewController];
        //[self.findNavigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-bar-background-light.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

        [self.findNavigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-bar-background-light.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [self.friendNavigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-bar-background-light.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [self.goNavigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-bar-background-light.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [self.settingNavigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-bar-background-light.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


        NSArray *allViewController = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.findNavigationController,self.friendNavigationController,self.goNavigationController,self.settingNavigationController, nil];
        self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
        [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:allViewController];
        UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
        [self.view addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
        [window setRootViewController:self];
    }
```

I want to create a `TabBarController` in `RegisterViewController`. How can I do it?
In `AppDelegate.m` I have an if which does: if already **login** then create `TabBarController`, if not go to `RegisterViewController`, then if **register** complete I want to create `TabBarController`. How to do this? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856933/tabbar-in-second-view/13857070#13857070

Comment: RegisterViewController didn't need TabBar, can i hidden it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273563/hide-uitabbar-when-pushed-while-retaining-touch/11273959#11273959

Answer (score 0):

You could just show your login and register views on top of `tabBarController.view` by `[self.tabBarController presentViewController:]` or such.

Answer (score 0):

Make public method in AppDelegate and create there tabbar as usual.
And call this method where you need:

```
[(ASAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]yourMethod]
```