# ios UITabBarController change to another UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Is it possible to redesign a UITabBarController when clicking on a UITabBarItem?

When starting the app I want to have 5 UITabBarItems:

```
self.myTabBarController = [CustomTabbarControllerViewController alloc] init];
self.myTabBarController.viewControllers = @[controller1, controller2, controller3, controller4, controller5];
..
```

When I ll click on controller2 I would like `myTabBarController.viewController to contain controllerA, controllerB, controllerC`. `controllerA` will bring the previous tabBarController.

I tried to find some examples on the internet, but i couldn t find any.

Answer (score 0):

You can make 2 tabBarController and make then hidden and show.
If you do this thing in single TabBarController then it will remove and add your viewController all time.

So best way to do is use 2 tabBarController in appDelegate.

Comment: how can i hide a tabBarController? Using myTabBarController2.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273563/hide-uitabbar-when-pushed-while-retaining-touch/11273959#11273959

Comment: or [self.tabBarController.view setHidden:YES];

Comment: also how to check in AppDelegate if a UITabBarItem for viewController 2 is clicked in order to make the second tabBarController visible and make the first one hidden?

Comment: I have this error message: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'. Could this be because the first tabBarController already has 5 item defined? From what I ve read...iOS has a limit set to the number of tabBarItems and it s equal to 5.

Comment: You can implement UITabBarDelegate delegate, and didSelectItem